# Why do we have to embed columns in Deep Neural Network but not in Linear Classifier in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, classification

I do understand the reason for the conversion in DNN part because we have to convert our features into numbers to feed the network. However, I did not understand why we do not have to do the same when training a linear classifier? How does it use a column that consists of characters for instance? Have I misunderstood the whole thing or is there a reason behind this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This somewhat depends on which classifier you're thinking of, but usually you do have to convert your text categories to some sort of numeric encoding to feed into the model

There are a few ways to do this, here's a couple of examples:

**Integer encoding**

Let's say your feature is "intensity of physical activity" and your categories are `low`, `medium`, and `high`

In this case we have ordinal information (i.e. they are ordered) so one way to preserve information about order is to recode each text category to a number. So instead of feeding in text: `low, medium, high`, we can instead feed in numbers: `1, 2, 3`

**One-hot encoding**

Let's say you have an input variable that has no natural order (i.e. a nominal variable). For example, a feature called "animals" might contain `cat`, `dog`, and `sheep`

Here, it may not be a good idea to encode the categories as integers because you'd be implying an ordering of the categories when there isn't one.

Instead, you can create one-hot vectors. Each category is represented by a vector, where `1` indicates membership to a particular category. When you feed the "animals" feature into your model you'd be feeding in a vector instead of text/single number:

```
cat  =  [1, 0, 0]
dog  =  [0, 1, 0]
sheep = [0, 0, 1]
```